# Count the number of bijective functions that don't fix any element

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $X = \{f:S \rightarrow S | f \text{ is bijective and } f(x) \neq x \text{ for each } x \in S\}$. How could we count |X|?

Comment: With four elements you can really count them by hand (there are only $24$ bijections after all). In general, these are called [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) and there are good recursive ways to count them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this I think, is by Inclusion-Exclusion, but we can also argue as follows, using only basic facts abouts permutations.

Suppose $\vert X\vert =n$ and let $D(n)$ be the number of derangements of $X$. We know that the total number of permutations is $n!$.

The number of permutations that do not fix any element is of course, $D(n)$, which may be expressed

$\binom{n}{0}\cdot D(n)\tag1$.

Now, suppose we want to count the number of permutations that fix $exactly$ one element of $X$. We have $n$ choices for the fixed element. The remaining $n-1$ elements will be shuffled in such a way that no element is mapped to itself by any permutation, and so by definition, the number of permutations  in this case is $D(n-1)$ so the total number of permutations that fix one and only one element of $X$ is

$n\cdot D(n-1)=\binom{n}{1}\cdot D(n-1)\tag2$.

In general, for $0\le k\le n$, if we want to count the number of permutations that fix $exactly$ $k$ elements, we choose the elements to fix in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, and note that the remaining elements are not fixed by any permutation, so the total number of permutations that fix exactly $k$ elements is

$\binom{n}{k}\cdot D(n-k)\tag3$.

If we sum over all of these individual steps, we get the total number of permutations:

$n!=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}D(n-k)\tag{4}$.

Letting $k=0$,we can solve for $D(n)$:

$D(n)=n!-\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}D(n-k)\tag{5}$